# Hybris - Navigation linking - how to remove links from top level

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am building the product navigation within the *Hybris CMS*, but the top level links won't work without being assigned to link to a page.

I only want the top level to reveal `sub-nav` items when clicked or hovered over.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks I solved my own problem by adding a hashtag in the URL field. Now the navigation items are there but they don't link anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Hybris WCMS, go to the 'Navigation' menu in the top,left of the wcms. Than just remove all targets that are assigned to the Navigation Nodes on the top level.

BR